# Why is Earth a sphere?

Tags: earth

Earth (and all of its 'neighbors') is a spheroid. Why is this?

Earth could've been a cube, a tetrahedron (pyramid) or really *any* shape! But why a sphere?

Comment: @FlorinAndrei yes, either [Why are planets spherical?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/1359/7982) as you point out, or  [Why does gravity make everything round?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/24698/7982) This is certainly a good question, but it's been asked before.